Tortoise Git Как в ветку залить контент другой ветки, избежав всех конфликтов и потери истории?
Есть ветка b0.
Чтобы пробовать разные доработки дополнительно была создана ветка b1. После этого в обе ветки было сделано независимо по несколько коммитов.
В результате возникла потребность "откинуть" все текущие изменения ветки b1 и привести её к текущему состоянию ветки b0. Так, чтобы сохранилась история обоих веток.
Было сделано с помощью консоли следующее:
git commit-tree -p origin/feature/b1 -p origin/feature/b0 -m "Overriding b1 with b0" origin/feature/b1^{tree}
<в ответ git выдаст хэш нового коммита>
git merge --ff <хэш нового коммита>

Это было взято из Хабр Q&A
Можно ли это сделать с помощью Tortoise git?

создайте новую от b0 да и все

Если b1 приводится  к изнапчальному состоянию, значит смысла во всех изменениях нет. А, значит, и историю этих изменений хранить нет смысла. Поэтому достаточно удалить ветку и отпачковаться от b0
